# Python regex matching words with repeating consonant

Tags: python, regex

First off, this is homework. (I couldn't use a tag in the title and nothing showed up in the tag list at the bottom for homework, so please let me know if I should EDIT something else regarding this matter).

So I have been reading through the python docs and scavenging SO, finding several solutions that are close to what I want, but not exact.

I have a dictionary which I read in to a string:

```
a
aa
aabbaa
...
z
```

We are practicing various regex patters on this data. 
The specific problem here is to return a list of words which match the pattern, NOT tuples with the groups within each match.

For example:

Given a subset of this dictionary like:

```
someword
sommmmmeword
someworddddd
sooooomeword
```

I want to return:

```
['sommmmmword', 'someworddddd']
```

NOT:

```
[('sommmmword', 'mmmmm', ...), ...] # or any other variant
```

EDIT:

My reasoning behind the above example, is that I want to see how I can avoid making a second pass over the results. That is instead of saying:

```
res = re.match(re.compile(r'pattern'), dictionary)
return [r[0] for r in res]
```

I specifically want a mechanism where I can just use:

```
return re.match(re.compile(r'pattern'), dictionary)
```

I know that may sound silly, but I am doing this to really dig into regex. I mention this at the bottom.

This is what I have tried:

```
# learned about back refs
r'\b([b-z&&[^eiou]])\1+\b' -> # nothing

# back refs were weird, I want to match something N times
r'\b[b-z&&[^eiou]]{2}\b' -> # nothing
```

Somewhere in testing I noticed a pattern returning things like `'\nsomeword'`. I couldn't figure out what it was but if I find the pattern again I will include it here for completeness.

```
# Maybe the \b word markers don't work how I think?
r'.*[b-z&&[^eiou]]{2}' -> # still nothing

# Okay lets just try to match something in between anything
r'.*[b-z&&[^eiou]].*' -> # nope

# Since its words, maybe I should be more explicit.
r'[a-z]*[b-z&&[^eiou]][a-z]*' -> # still nope

# Decided to go back to grouping.
r'([b-z&&[^eiou]])(\1)'  # I realize set difference may be the issue

# I saw someone (on SO) use set difference claiming it works
#  but I gave up on it...

# OKAY getting close
r'(([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])(\2))' -> [('ll', 'l', 'l'), ...]

# Trying the the previous ones without set difference 
r'\b(.*(?:[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]{3}).*)\b'  -> # returned everything (all words)

# Here I realize I need a non-greedy leading pattern (.* -> .*?)
r'\b(.*?(?:[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]{3}).*)\b' ->  # still everything

# Maybe I need the comma in {3,} to get anything 3 or more
r'\b(.*?(?:[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]{3,}).*)\b' ->  # still everything

# okay I'll try a 1 line test just in case
r'\b(.*?([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])(\2{3,}).*)\b'  
    # Using 'asdfdffff' -> [('asdfdffff', 'f', 'fff')]
    # Using dictionary -> []  # WAIT WHAT?!
```

How does this last one work? Maybe there there are no 3+ repeating consonant words? I'm using `/usr/share/dict/cracklib-small` on my schools server which is about 50,000 words I think.

I am still working on this but any advice would be awesome.

One thing I find curious is that you can not back reference a non-capturing group. If I want to output only the full word, I use (?:...) to avoid capture, but then I can not back reference. Obviously I could leave the captures, loop over the results and filter out the extra stuff, but I absolutely want to figure this out using ONLY regex!

Perhaps there is a way to do the non-capture, but still allow back reference? Or maybe there is an entirely different expression I haven't tested yet.

Comment: Homework is fine to ask here when you have made efforts for it :) Can you please share the logic behind `['sommmmmword', 'someworddddd']` and not `[('sommmmword', 'mmmmm', ...), ...]` On what basis these two are differentiated?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry if that seemed confusing. I put in an edit.

Comment: 1) Use `re.findall` to get all the results, not `re.match` (that only searches for  1 match and only at the string start). 2)`[b-z&&[^eiou]]` is a Java/ICU regex, this syntax is not supported by Python `re`. 3) To avoid "extra" values in tuples with `re.findall`, *do not* use capturing groups. If you need backreferences, use `re.finditer` instead of `re.findall` and access `.group()`  of each match.

Comment: Is http://ideone.com/Px2Qmx what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some points to consider:

1. Use `re.findall` to get all the results, not `re.match` (that only searches for  1 match and only at the string start).
2. `[b-z&&[^eiou]]` is a Java/ICU regex, this syntax is not supported by Python `re`. In Python, you can either redefine the ranges to skip the vowels, or use `(?![eiou])[b-z]`.
3. To avoid "extra" values in tuples with `re.findall`, *do not* use capturing groups. If you need backreferences, use `re.finditer` instead of `re.findall` and access `.group()`  of each match.

Coming back to the question, how you can use  a backreference and still get the whole match, here is a [working demo](http://ideone.com/Px2Qmx):

```
import re
s = """someword
sommmmmeword
someworddddd
sooooomeword"""
res =[x.group() for x in re.finditer(r"\w*([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])\1\w*", s)]
print(res)
# => ['sommmmmeword', 'someworddddd']
```

Comment: Ah, I was using fiindall, I just mistyped the example. But I did not try finditer! I thought it was just a generator for findall. I will test this out once I am home! Thank you.  Also as a side note, instead of explicitly saying '\1\1\1\1...' to gather N copies of the match, could I just use \1{N} without grouping it?

Comment: You may use a quantifier with a backreference (=quantify a backreference) the same way as any atom: `\1{4}`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FU9R61/1).